# How do i get rid of duplicated local variables

Tags: automated-testing, java, testng

I have a multiple drop-downs and need to automate them.

I added the code below, how do I add them in one step?

or

make it easier

or

how do I add them in one function?

I'm using eclipse and TestNG plugin with selenium and maven dependencies

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class InstallationPage extends CreateNewStore {
@FindBy(id ="is-selling")
WebElement firstSelection;

@FindBy(name="setting[selling_channels][]")
WebElement secondSelection;

@FindBy(id = "products-select")
WebElement thirdSelection;

@FindBy(id = "range-select")
WebElement fourthSelection;

@FindBy(id= "industry-select")
WebElement fifthSelection;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@value='Yes']")
WebElement firstRadio;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@value='No']")
WebElement seondRadio;


public void InstallationSteps() 
{ 
Select selectObject = new Select(firstSelection); 
selectObject.selectByIndex(2);
 Select selectObject = new Select(secondSelection); 
selectObject.selectByIndex(3); 
Select selectObject = new Select(thirdSelection);
 selectObject.selectByIndex(2); 
Select selectObject = new Select(fourthSelection);
 selectObject.selectByIndex(2); 
Select selectObject = new Select(fifthSelection); 
selectObject.selectByIndex(2);

} }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have local variables?
You can simply act on the objects

```
new Select(firstSelection).selectByIndex(2);
new Select(secondSelection).selectByIndex(2);
...
```

Or you can have a list:

```
List selects = Arrays.asList(new Select(firstSelection), new Select(secondSelection), ...);
selects.stream().forEach(select -> select.selectByIndex(2))
```